# WAL file is from different database system

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, wal

Am  using WAL E  and trying to restore  a  postgresql  database  i get the  error  `WAL file is from different database system: WAL file database system identifier is 6422218584094261886, pg_control database system identifier is 6338745400937582833`

How can i  force the  postgresql  database  to  use the database  identifier  of the WAL  archive or  force WAL  archive  to use the  Database  system identifier  of  the database

Comment: You can't replay WAL from one installation of PostgreSQL into a different one (unless it is a replica). If you *really* *really* know what you are doing you can overwrite the id on the target db. Search the postgresql.org mailing list archives for some details. I don't think you do know what you are doing or you'd have searched the mailing lists already.

Comment: @RichardHuxton ,  the machine crashed and  i had  WAL files  backups  in the  Google cloud  ,  i  had  postgresql 9.6  installed  in  ubuntu  and  i  just brought  up a  new instance  and  tried to  restore the  WAL files  , some guidance  would be  very helpful

Comment: Please share the commands you're executing to get the above error.  I strongly suspect that you're doing WAL-E restore incorrectly.

Also, don't tag this question with 3 different PostgreSQL versions you're not using.

Comment: @FuzzyChef  i was able  to  recover  the database  from a  WAL-E  basebackup  in  google-drive

Answer (score 1):

To restore the WAL files you will need your original base-backup and all the WAL files from that point forwards. The WAL files themselves list the changes to a base backup.

Comment: using a WAL-E  base-backup  stored  in  google cloud  storage by wal-e   i was able  to  recover  the  whole  data  .

Answer (score 1):

Did you move the pg data dir while the database was still running?

Had the same problem when migrating from one server node to the other, moving the postgres data dir with scp to the other node. When starting the docker container on the new node, i got this error in docker log -f. It turned out that i was copying the dirs while the postgres docker container on the source node was still running.